# how to remove hive new line character from the data stored in AVRO format

Tags: hive

I had a data saved in Azure blob in AVRO format. I need to remove hive new line characters from the data while executing the select query. The output of the hive select query should not contain hive new line character. I am currently using **regexp_replace({0}, '\t|\r\n|\n', ' ')** to replace the new line character with space. But, its not working as per the need.

Comment: What is the difference between the expected and the current output ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace the newline char present in that specific column with some other char, like this

```
select regexp_replace(col_which_has_new_line,"\n","") from tbl;
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but this would not work for \r\n cases right?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if I had an Address hive table with columns AddressId, FullAddress, UpdatedDate and UpdatedBy.
Now the records already present is like the below:

AddressId     FullAddress     UpdatedDate     UpdatedBy
123           Apartment 601,  2015-01-22      XYZ
              XYZ Street,
              XYZ

After selecting the data from hive table, I need the out shown below:

AddressId FullAddress                   UpdatedDate                UpdatedBy
123       Apartment 601,XYZ Street,XYZ  2015-01-22                 XYZ

Thanks.

Comment: Or rather I can say I want the column Address value to be in single line

Thanks.

Comment: did you get a solution, Apsara?

Comment: If you are adding more information to the question, update the question or add comment to the question. Do not add it as an answer.